# Properly cast a UILabel

Tags: ios, casting, uilabel

I've created a custom sub-class GTLabel of UILabel to have the right font, size, color, etc...

When I create a GTLabel programmatically, everything works fine. When I create a UILabel in the IB, I just have to change its class into GTLabel and it works.

Now when I have a UIButton, with a titleLabel, I would like to transform this UILabel into a GTLabel.

I've created a class method in GTLabel :

```
+ (GTLabel*)labelFromLabel:(UILabel*)label
{
    ...

    return myGTLabel;
}
```

I don't really see how I'm suppose to proceed in this method.

Am I suppose to do as bellow?

```
GTLabel *myGTLabel = [[GTLabel alloc] init];
// Get all the properties of the original label
myGTLabel.text = label.text;
myGTLabel.frame = label.frame;
// Do the modifications 
myGTLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Light"
                                 size:label.font.pointSize];
```

The idea would be to do something like

```
myButton.titleLabel = [GTLabel labelFromLabel:myButton.titleLabel];
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: we need your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your custom UIButton ( eg. GTButton ) and redefine titleLabel property, setting the same propertylabel  used for your GTLabel

something like:

```
#import "GTButton.h"

@implementation GTButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


-(UILabel *)titleLabel
{
    UILabel* parentLabel = [super titleLabel];

    parentLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Light"
                                     size:parentLabel.font.pointSize];
    // ... set all your attributes

    return parentLabel;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

**titleLabel** method of UIButton is read-only.

Although this property is read-only, its own properties are read/write. Use these properties primarily to configure the text of the button.

For example:

```
UIButton *button                  = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
button.titleLabel.font            = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode   = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
```

Create custom class for UIButton as you create for label and set property in it.